# xtrabackup can not use tar

Tags: mysql, backup

I use

> innobackupex --user=root --password=root --stream=tar ./ | gzip - >
>   backup.tar.gz

to backup a MySQL, but the backup.tar.gz only containes one file ".\backup-my.cnf", what's wrong?
--stream=xbstream is OK.“backup.xbstream” will containes all of the files.

> MySQL:5.5,xtrabackup:2.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake.
The xtrabackup manual have said that : tar the gz file must use -i. I missed the -i, so I can get only one file.